# String replace in Array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, replace, preg-replace

Here is my Response for the validation message

```
{"success":"0","message":{"Mobile":["The mobile field is required."],"DeviceId":["The device id field is required."]}}
```

Where my code is

```
$Response = array('success' => '0', 'message' => $validation->messages());
return json_encode($Response);
```

I want to remove all the `[` and `]` so my reponse should be

```
{"success":"0","message":{"Mobile":"The mobile field is required.","DeviceId":"The device id field is required."}}
```

I tried with

```
$err = str_replace("[", "", $validation->messages());
$error = str_replace("]", "", $err);
$Response = array('success' => '0', 'message' => $error);
return json_encode($Response);
```

I am getting

```
{"success":"0","message":"{\"Mobile\":\"The mobile field is required.\",\"DeviceId\":\"The device id field is required.\"}"}
```

I even tried with

```
$err = str_replace("[", " ", $validation->messages());
```

How can i do this to remove only the `[` and `]` and the `[` so that my output should be

```
{"success":"0","message":{"Mobile":"The mobile field is required.","DeviceId":"The device id field is required."}}
```

Comment: seems another dimension inside `$validation->messages()`. just reassign them then encode.

Answer (score 0):

What you said you are getting matches what you said you want to get. Other then the \" which is actually just PHP's way of making " as part of the string. If you echo what you are getting it should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$obj = json_decode($validation->messages(), true);
foreach($obj as $k=>$v) $obj[$k] = $v[0];
$validation_messages = json_encode($obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$b = preg_replace('/\[|\]/', "", $validation->messages());
echo $b;
```